# I am getting an error while executing this stored function in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, function

My stored function requires an input and should return the number of members that have won atleast two awards ...

Here is my Code;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculateaward
(
  i_PLAYERID VARCHAR2  
) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 
cnt NUMBER;
BEGIN

SELECT * INTO cnt FROM 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS NOM FROM
  (
    SELECT PLAYERID, USERNAME FROM MEMBER R
    WHERE R.USERNAME IN
    (
      SELECT USERNAME FROM 
      (
        SELECT USERNAME, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM MEMBERAWARD
        GROUP BY USERNAME
      )
      WHERE cnt >= 2
    )
  )
  WHERE player= I_PLAYERID
  GROUP BY PLAYERID
);

  RETURN cnt;
END calculateaward;
```

I am trying to execute the function as follow 
exec calculateaward('P0001') but it does not work , please help .

Comment: Define "does not work."  What is the expected behavior and what is the observed behavior?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Since the DDL and Data is not provided, giving the error code/message can help resolving the issue...

Answer (score 3):

You cannot execute a function using exec unlike stored procedures..Instead try this:

```
SELECT calculateaward('P0001') FROM DUAL;
```

Also, why define the function as returning a VARCHAR2 when you are returning a NUMBER, it's not an error since the number will be cast to  VARCHAR2 automatically, but its always better to return the same datatype as defined by returns

Comment: Actually we can EXECUTE functions.

Comment: @APC: Can you provide a sample?

Answer (score 2):

Functions return things: that's what distinguishes them from procedures.  So when we execute them we need to provide a receptacle for the returned value:

In SQL*Plus that would be

```
SQL>   var whatever varchar2(30)
SQL>   exec :whatever := calculateaward('P0001')
```

By the way, as your function executes a query whose resulot is a COUNT, the returned value ought to have a datatype of NUMBER rather than VARCHAR2.